# Warning in C++17 when including XPM image

Tags: c++, c++17

I'm working on a C++ project that compiled with the `std=c++17` and `-Wall` flags. I'm generally required to clear warnings.

I've tried including an `xpm` image produced with an online tool from a png file, and got the following warning:

`warning: ISO C++ forbids converting a string constant to 'char*' [-Wwrite-strings]`

The worst part is that this message is repeated over and over, to the point my console no longer holds error messages.

Is there any way I can suppress this warning while keeping both flags? Any modification I could do on the xpm file, perhaps?

Comment: Is the error coming from your code, or the xpm library you are using?

Comment: I assume the api is requesting `char*` and you are passing a literal like `"string"` which is should technically decay to `const char*` instead of `char*` which is what the warning is about,

Comment: In C++ all literal strings are *constant* arrays of characters. Therefore you need a `const char*` type to refer to them. It seems the code you include is using plain `char *` (which is valid in C).

Comment: Would really need to know a bit more about what you are doing - is this a header include causing this? is this seen in 3rd party code your compiling? I'd not advise doing the following, but you can if stuck. Try adding this prior to the header you are including (or use ignored instead):  #pragma GCC diagnostic warning "-Wwrite-strings"

Comment: @NathanOliver : The appointed line if on the .xmp file.

Comment: By the way, note that this behavior isn't new in C++17, it have been in C++ since before the first standard IIRC.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude It [seems](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/string_literal) the literals were always `const`, but pre-C++11 you could magically convert them to `char *`.

Comment: @NeilMcGill : I basically want to include an image within an executable build with wxWidgets. I am required to have it packed in the executable (cannot have it as a separate file on the deployed program, and I need to address compiling warnings due to company standards.

Comment: Why not simply edit the xpm file and change `char *` to `const char *`?

Comment: @JesperJuhl : The XPM as I've got started with `static char *var_name[] = {`. It didn't occur to me that I could or should  change it to `const char *var_name[] = {`. This seems simpler than temporarily removing a warning message. If you want to explain a bit more and add it as a question, I'll likely accept it.

Comment: @Mefitico added an answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The tool you used to create the XPM file likely only considered the C language (or pre-standard C++) where lack of `const` is not an error. In C++, however, a string literal is `const` and the language enforce that. You cannot change the *thing*, so a `char*` to it makes no sense and should be a `const char*`.

The easiest solution is to simply edit your xpm file and add `const`.

Comment: Didn't the lack of const in that context became an error only after C++11? `char* s = "Hello";` was only deprecated in C++03 if I recall correctly,

Comment: @Ayxan I don't recall exactly, to be honest. But even before it became deprecated, using `const` was always the more correct/proper thing to do.

Answer (score -1):

It is a bit late to answer but I solved that problem by putting a line with `const`, before the line where the xpm is included.

```
const // to avoid the warning: ISO C ++ forbids converting a string constant to 'char *' [-Wwrite-strings]
#include "image.xpm"
```

Comment: Although this may work, it relies on the relevant 'error' line being the first in the included file. That may change if the packaged is updated.

Comment: Never seen this ugly C syntax use

Answer (score -2):

You could temporarily [silence the warning](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Diagnostic-Pragmas.html) when including an xpm file:

```
#pragma GCC diagnostic push
#pragma GCC diagnostic ignored "-Wwrite-strings"
#include "banana.xpm"
#pragma GCC diagnostic pop
```

The approach is the same for Clang, just replace `GCC` by `clang`.

Comment: *"same for Clang, just replace GCC by clang."* Clang understands GCC pragmas as is, so you don't have to do that.

Comment: yup. This works. I'll wait a while before accepting to see if other answers show up.

Comment: Just silencing compiler warnings is *very rarely* the right solution. The right solution is usually to address the actual underlying reason for the warning.

Comment: Given the context, this means an extra post-processing step for every image. For that effort, you might as well choose to compile the xpm files as C instead or use `ld`'s binary embedding.